# Reducing the number of comparisons performed when matching between two String arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, performance, comparison

I am comparing three arrays of `String`s using the two classes below. Without using any hash maps or changing the structure of my code too much (I can't change the signature of `findMatchingElements()`), is there a way to minimize the number of comparisons that my method makes, in order to construct the new array of shared elements?

In TestRun.java I tested my code on three arrays with 8 elements each, which resulted in 46 comparisons made. I want to achieve a lower number of comparisons. Is there a way?

I tried using the `remove()` method to remove a string from the collection once it was successfully compared to a matching element from the query collection. That prevented some redundant comparisons, but it did not result in a significant reduction.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CommonElements {

    int originalCollectionCount = 0;  
    Object[] originalCollections;    
    int listCount = 1;
    int matchCount;
    int comparisonCount = 0;                

    public Comparable[] findMatchingItems(Object[] collections)
    {   

        String[] queryArray = (String[])collections[0]; 
        String[] secondaryArray = (String[])collections[1];

        ArrayList<String> queryList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(queryArray));
        ArrayList<String> secondaryList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(secondaryArray));
        ArrayList<String> commonList = new ArrayList();       

        int  i = 0;

        if(listCount == 1){  
            originalCollectionCount = collections.length;
            originalCollections = collections;
        }

        listCount ++;                               

        for(String x:queryList)
        {            
            for(String y:secondaryList)
            {                      
                comparisonCount++;                 
                if(x.compareTo(y) == 0)
                { 
                    commonList.add(x); //add mutually shared item to commonList
                    secondaryList.remove(y); //remove mutually shared item from consideration
                    if(originalCollectionCount == listCount) //if every list has been examined
                    {
                        System.out.println(commonList.get(i));                                                    
                    }
                    i++;  
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        String[] commonListResult = new String[commonList.size()];
        commonList.toArray(commonListResult);           

        if(originalCollectionCount > listCount){ 
            findMatchingItems(new Object[] {commonListResult,originalCollections[listCount]});}

        if (collections.length == 0) {
            return new Comparable[0];
        } else if (collections.length == 1) {
            return (Comparable[]) collections[0];
        }                
        return commonListResult;
    }

    public int getComparisons(){
        return comparisonCount;}        
}


    public class TestRun {

private final static String[] COLLECTION_5_1 = {"Pittsburgh", "New York", "Chicago", "Cleveland", "Miami", "Dallas", "Atlanta", "Detroit"};
private final static String[] COLLECTION_5_2 = {"Dallas", "Atlanta", "Cleveland", "Chicago", "Washington", "Houston", "Baltimore", "Denver"};
private final static String[] COLLECTION_5_3 = {"Chicago", "Kansas City", "Cleveland", "Jacksonville", "Atlanta", "Tampa Bay", "Dallas", "Seattle"}; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestRun();       
    }

    public TestRun() {

        CommonElements commonElements = new CommonElements();                

        Object[] input = new Object[3];
        input[0] = COLLECTION_5_1;
        input[1] = COLLECTION_5_2;
        input[2] = COLLECTION_5_3;    

        System.out.println("Matching items:");
        commonElements.findMatchingItems(input);

        System.out.println(commonElements.comparisonCount + " comparisons made.");  



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a single advanced for loop as below provide the length for both array are same if not run throug it accordingly.

```
for(String str:arrayStr1){
if(arrayStr2.contains(str)){
newArray.add(str);
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't reduce the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list_5_1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(COLLECTION_5_1));
//[Pittsburgh, New York, Chicago, Cleveland, Miami, Dallas, Atlanta, Detroit]
List<String> list_5_2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(COLLECTION_5_2));
//[Dallas, Atlanta, Cleveland, Chicago, Washington, Houston, Baltimore, Denver]

list_5_1.retainAll(list_5_2);
//[Chicago, Cleveland, Dallas, Atlanta]

We have to pass list returned from Arrays.asList, as Arrays.asList method returns only immutable list.
```

Comment: This is fine, but doesn't reduce the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

> am comparing three arrays of Strings using the two classes below. Without using any hash maps or changing the structure of my code too much (I can't change the signature of findMatchingElements()), is there a way to minimize the number of comparisons that my method makes, in order to construct the new array of shared elements?

Sure. Your nested loops have complexity of `O(m*n)`. When you create a temporary `HashMap`, you can reduce it to `O(m+n)` and gain a lot for big inputs. From practical POV, somewhere around length of 10 it should get faster than your solution.

I'm giving no code as it's too straightforward.